# How do I get previous data with respect to effective date in Oracle HCM cloud reporting in seperate column?

Tags: sql, oracle, report

```
(
    select 
      ppnf_sup.full_name 
    FROM 
      per_all_people_f papf_sup, 
      per_person_names_f ppnf_sup, 
      per_assignment_supervisors_f pasf1 
    where 
      1 = 1 
      and papf_sup.person_id = ppnf_sup.person_id 
      AND ppnf_sup.person_id = pasf1.manager_id 
      AND pasf1.assignment_id = paam.assignment_id 
      AND pasf1.primary_flag = 'Y' 
      AND pasf1.manager_type = 'LINE_MANAGER' 
      AND ppnf_sup.name_type = 'GLOBAL' 


   AND MIN(  papf_sup.effective_start_date, -1 ) AND  papf_sup.effective_end_date 

   AND MIN(  pasf1.effective_start_date ,  -1 )   AND pasf1.effective_end_date
   AND ppnf_sup.effective_end_date = (select MIN(ppnf_sup1.effective_start_date)-1)

      FROM 
      per_all_people_f papf_sup1, 
      per_person_names_f ppnf_sup1, 
      per_assignment_supervisors_f pasf2 
    where 
      1 = 1 
      and papf_sup1.person_id = ppnf_sup1.person_id 
      AND ppnf_sup1.person_id = pasf2.manager_id 
      AND pasf2.assignment_id = paam.assignment_id 
      AND pasf2.primary_flag = 'Y' 
      AND pasf2.manager_type = 'LINE_MANAGER' 
      AND ppnf_sup1.name_type = 'GLOBAL' 
  AND trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN papf_sup1.effective_start_date AND papf_sup1.effective_end_date 
 AND trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN pasf2.effective_start_date AND pasf2.effective_end_date
  group by person_id

)   prev_Sup_name,
```

How can I achieve this code works for previous data like curr job title is SR manager and prev job title was manager?

Comment: Your question is not clear and not even logic of the query. Please edit the question and share sample data, expected output, somewhat table structures.

Comment: Also you forgot to include `per_all_assigments_m` which is required to map person and supervisor